# How to fetch values from bytes?

Tags: python, post, https, byte, response

After POST request I am getting a response which is in bytes but I want to fetch my access_token, refresh_token how it will be possible.

```
payload = 'grant_type=authorization_code&code=' + self.response_code + '&redirect_uri=' + self.redirect_uri
        auth = self.client_id+':'+self.client_secret
        endcoded_u = base64.b64encode(auth.encode("ascii")).decode("ascii")
        response = requests.post(
            url='https://api.getbase.com/oauth2/token',
            headers={
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Authorization': 'Basic %s' % endcoded_u,
            },
            data=payload,
            verify=True
        )
b'{"access_token":"5716f50fead975aa81340757cadbb1a2154681d9750c53abe4672143c7d938c3","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":3600,"refresh_token":"365e14fbd4d0e6a25486bf11cea3ebe84dbf5f2485fd95443a579c04f75e5e6e","scope":"read write profile sync"}'
```

any help?

Comment: Could you paste the code ? Maybe you are not reading it right

Comment: Where are you getting this string from ? The `response` ? If yes, then `response.json()` should directly give you the `dict` and then you can access the `access_token` directly

Comment: I dont know why people degrade my question :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
import json

data = b'{"access_token":"5716f50fead975aa81340757cadbb1a2154681d9750c53abe4672143c7d938c3","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":3600,"refresh_token":"365e14fbd4d0e6a25486bf11cea3ebe84dbf5f2485fd95443a579c04f75e5e6e","scope":"read write profile sync"}'
data = json.loads(data.decode())

print(data.get("access_token"))
# '5716f50fead975aa81340757cadbb1a2154681d9750c53abe4672143c7d938c3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
import json
token_bytes=b'{"access_token":"5716f50fead975aa81340757cadbb1a2154681d9750c53abe4672143c7d938c3","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":3600,"refresh_token":"365e14fbd4d0e6a25486bf11cea3ebe84dbf5f2485fd95443a579c04f75e5e6e","scope":"read write profile sync"}'

token_byte_string=token_bytes.decode("utf-8") #decode bytes to string

response = json.loads(token_byte_string) # built a dict from above string

response["access_token"] # this is your access token
```